# Android: Not receiving SMS delivered confirmation in emulator

Tags: android, sms, confirmation

What I try to do is to send sms to another phone and get the confirmation if the sms is delivered or not.
Now, only confirmation that sms has been sent works. So I get message that my sms has been sent but then I get nothing.
I'm using 2 emulators to test it, but I don't think it is the problem. Unfortunetly I don't have mobile phone with andoid a the moment :(

My code looks like this:

```
private void sendSms(String txt, String phone){
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(act, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(act, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

      //---when the SMS has been sent---
        act.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(act, "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(act, "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(act, "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(act, "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(act, "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        act.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {               
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(act, "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(act, "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, txt, sentPI, deliveredPI);  
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the ["SMS Messaging in Android"-tutorial on mobiforge.com](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android), the delivery status report doesn't work with emulators:

> When it is successfully delivered, it will display a "SMS delivered" message. Note that for testing using the emulator, when an SMS is successfully delivered, the "SMS delivered" message does not appear; this only works for real devices.